# how can I use a variable to invoke a different r.color

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to put "colorSRMx" on a variable and call it from something like this. how can I write a more efficient code.

`colorint = getColor(resources, R.color."VARIABLE", null)`

```
sbarSRMColor.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(object :SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener {
            override fun onProgressChanged(seekBar: SeekBar?, progress: Int, fromUser: Boolean) {
                txtsrm =  progress.toString()
                when (txtsrm) {
                    "1" -> colorint    = getColor(resources,R.color.colorSRM1,null)
                    "2" -> colorint    = getColor(resources,R.color.colorSRM2,null)
                    "3" -> colorint    = getColor(resources,R.color.colorSRM3,null)
                    "4" -> colorint    = getColor(resources,R.color.colorSRM4,null)
                    // and so on...
                }

                value.setBackgroundColor(colorint)
            }
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retrieve a color from values/colors.xml using a variable in name (R.color.name + variable)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10963931/retrieve-a-color-from-values-colors-xml-using-a-variable-in-name-r-color-name)

Comment: Be careful if using @Mosius link and proguard. Add rules to keep the resources manually if you don't use them elsewhere, but only through reflection.

Answer (score 0):

```
fun Activity.parseColorSafe(colorString: String): Int{
    return try {
        Color.parseColor(colorString)
    } catch (exception: Exception) {
        resources.getColor(R.color.transparent)
    }
}
```

In your activity, use method like `parseColorSafe(colorSRM1)`